# pass model through ajax.beginform

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Model:

```
 public class AdminViewModel {
    public AdminViewModel()
    {

    }
    public Reseller CurrentReseller { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Reseller> AllResellers { get; set; }
    public ResellerWebSetting CurrentResellerWebSettings { get; set; }

    public ResellerPresaleMessage PreSaleMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult RenderPartials(AdminViewModel model)
    {
         //do stuff with model
         return PartialView("_SellerWebSettings", model);//sending model back with more info
    }
```

View:

```
@model CellularFlashingMVC.Models.ViewModels.AdminViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RenderPartials", "Admin", new { @model = Model  }, new AjaxOptions {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        LoadingElementDuration = 500,
        LoadingElementId = "AjaxLoading",
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    }, new { id = "DDLReseller" })) {
        <div>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(rs => rs.CurrentReseller.RouteName)
            .Name("CurReseller")
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("Name")
            .Events(e => e.Change("OnCurResellerChanged"))
            .DataSource(source => {
                source.Read(read => {
                    read.Action("GetResellers", "Admin");
                });
            }).OptionLabel("-- Select a Reseller --"))
            //@Html.Hidden("model", Model) this didn't work either
        </div>
    }

 <script>



function OnCurResellerChanged() {
      $("#DDLReseller").submit();
  }
 </script>
```

Why I don't get or understand is it that in my controller method, the "model" property is always null?  I've tried hidden fields, i've also tried doing hand written JS for $.ajax and having it serialize and it still was null. i'm not sure what is going on...

here's what i had for the custom JS.

```
 $.ajax({
                url: $("#CurReseller").attr('action'),
               type: $("#CurReseller").attr('method'),
                data: $("#CurReseller").serialize(),
               success: function (data) {
                   alert(data.Status);
                }
```

Comment: My only idea is that you are missing @model yourproject.models.AdminViewModel in the first line of your view

Comment: Sorry I didn't have that at the top of this post, it is there, I was only pasting part of the view instead of the whole thing! Added that to avoid confusion. thanks! :)